# How to Disable audio jack detection in Debian based Linux (Kali Linux)

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

My audio jack is damaged, since it is damaged it always show the headphone is up, even if there is headphone, Is there anyway to disable audio jack detection, I only need in-built speaker and Bluetooth headphone, I want to disable the audio jack, I am using Debian based Linux

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable the "auto-mute mode" in the ALSA sound driver instead; that way, the state of the headphone jack would have no effect to the speaker use.

First, you'll need to identify the (current) index number of your built-in sound chip: run "amixer info -c 0" to identify the first sound card/chip, then increment the number to see any other sound devices. Once you know the number of your system's built-in sound chip, run `amixer -c <N> sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' Disabled`, replacing `<N>` with the correct number. After this, if your internal speaker is currently muted, you should be able to un-mute it using a regular audio mixer tool even if the audio jack currently detects a plug. This would allow you to still easily use the headphone jack later by just adjusting the mixer settings if the need arises.

Then run `sudo alsactl store` to make the new settings (disabling of auto-mute and unmuting of the speaker) persistent.

Or you might use the `hdajackretask` tool in the `alsa-tools` package to set the headphone jack to "Not Connected" and click on `Install Boot Override` to make it persistent. This would completely disable the headphone jack.

Comment: @telecoM bro a pop-up (Audio jack detection, which is very annoying)comes and goes every-time I open the laptop will this solution get rid of that too, bro what is meant by "regular audio mixer tool" , I am sorry actually I dont know that much bash script commands and when I run 'amixer info -c 0'  It says command not found